# Java : Is 'Square root of a negative number' a logical error or a runtime error?

Tags: java, exception, runtime, nan

I was solving a practice examination paper, and it had the question -
*Which of the following errors will the snippet produce ?* -

```
System.out.println(Math.sqrt(24-25));
```

*Logical, Runtime, Syntax*

I know it will give `NaN`, but can someone confirm what type it will be included in?
Thank you.

Comment: If it was a practice exam then just code it and run it. You don't need us to tell you.

Comment: Seems like an opinion-based question.  The code shown *doesn't* produce an error, it produces the correct and documented output that it's expected to.  One might refer to it as a "logical error" but that implies additional logic upstream from this single line of code, which isn't known here.

Comment: What it is is not a great test question. It's definitely not a syntax error. Whether NaN counts as a logical or a runtime error is somewhat subjective and we have no way to see into the test author's mind. Toss a coin.

Comment: Okay but..some sources online say that it is runtime error..

Comment: The most important source that matters in this case is the official documentation of that class and method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt-double- - And here it says nothing about runtime errors. (Compare with the documentation of method negateExact where it clearly states when an exception will be thrown: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#negateExact-int- )

Comment: sqrt is telling you at runtime that you have given it bad input, I am leaning more towards runtime error, but it's not a great example of one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which of the following errors will the snippet produce -
>
> ```
>  System.out.println(Math.sqrt(24-25));
> ```
>
> Logical, Runtime, Syntax.

This won't produce a syntax error or any other kind of compilation error<sup>1</sup>.

This won't produce a runtime error in the sense that that term is used in Java; i.e. no exception will be thrown.  The `sqrt` call terminates *normally* and returns a `NaN` value.  `NaN` is a well-defined value, per the Java Language spec and IEE floating point spec.

Is it a logical error?  That depends on the specification of your program.  But on the face of it, outputting "NaN" as the square root of -1 is a reasonable thing to do.

So, in the absence of a specification, I would be inclined to say that there is no error here at all.

However, in other contexts using a `NaN` generated by `sqrt` *could* be a logical error, and *could* indirectly give rise to runtime errors (in the Java sense).

The lesson is that it is not possible to classify errors without considering the context.  Even the meaning of the *types* of errors is context dependent<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - ... unless you shadow the standard `java.lang.Math` class.

2 - For instance, it depends on the precise definitions of "Logical error", "Runtime error", "Syntax error" and so on that you have been taught. Or the programming language you are using.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If it were a runtime error I would expect it to throw a `RuntimeErrorException` or perhaps just a `RuntimeException`.  These are `unchecked exceptions` and do not need to be caught.  Since the `Math.sqrt()` does not throw any exception `(nor does Math.log(0))` I do not consider them errors from the standpoint of Java.  But depending on the method, the results can still be compared to existing constants such as `Double.NaN`, `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`, and `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`. How the values are to be used later in subsequent calculations and if they cause incorrect computations, some (as I do ), might consider them logic errors.  But without more information it is not clear what the test question had in mind.

Comment: ...or is the problem to have a negative number have a sqrt. the problem one number must be positive and the other must be negative. That more would be specification convention in math AI compute rules.